# What happens if new-handler function in not written properly or can't free any more memory in c++

Tags: c++

A well written new-handler function should be "if it is not able to free any more memory, then either through exception or call exit() to terminate the program".

What happens if new-handler is not written in that way. Function is written such that it can try to free the memory that's it. what will happen in this case. where the control will be return??

and when new-handler is freeing the memory, who checks that now free memory is big enough to handle the new request.

Comment: you are probably looking for "C++ allocators"

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the handler set by [`std::set_new_handler`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/set_new_handler), then if the handler returns and `new` still can't allocate memory the handler will be called again, and again and again...

Comment: Thanks for quick response. So till when handler will be called?? I guess until it is giving some more memory to new. Now if new have enough memory to serve the request it will allocate memory. If Not what will happen? As we have override the default behavior of new (through bad_alloc exception).

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal As long as a handler returns and `new` still can't allocate the memory needed, the handler will be called. If the handler doesn't clear itself (i.e. installing the default handler), abort, or somehow manages to free up enough memory, it will be called forever.

Comment: That's interesting. So the program will be in infinite loop. Right?? Thanks for clearing the doubt.

Answer (score 0):

"Undefined Behavior". C++ doesn't try to protect you from yourself. If you violate the C++ rules, anything can happen.